# Unable to connect Vue app to my local port

Tags: vue.js, npm

I'm running ***npm run dev*** to connect my app to view in my browser and I keep getting this error:

---

```
    > sh:/Users/jasmineanderson/chibi/chibi_hub/client/node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server: Permission denied 
    > npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE 
    > npm ERR! errno 126 
    > npm ERR! chibi_hub@1.0.0 dev: `webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js` npm ERR! 
    > Exit status 126 npm ERR!  npm ERR!
    > Failed at the chibi_hub@1.0.0 dev script. npm ERR! 
    > This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output
    > above.
    > 
    > npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:   
    > /Users/jasmineanderson/.npm/_logs/2018-10-08T22_43_38_723Z-debug.log
```

---

I checked to make sure nothing else is running on port 8080 and I'm still getting the error

### This is the log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'dev' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.9.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle chibi_hub@1.0.0~predev: chibi_hub@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle chibi_hub@1.0.0~dev: chibi_hub@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle chibi_hub@1.0.0~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle chibi_hub@1.0.0~dev: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/jasmineanderson/chibi/chibi_hub/client/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
9 verbose lifecycle chibi_hub@1.0.0~dev: CWD: /Users/jasmineanderson/chibi/chibi_hub/client
10 silly lifecycle chibi_hub@1.0.0~dev: Args: [ '-c',
10 silly lifecycle   'webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle chibi_hub@1.0.0~dev: Returned: code: 126  signal: null
12 info lifecycle chibi_hub@1.0.0~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: chibi_hub@1.0.0 dev: `webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 126
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:250:5)
14 verbose pkgid chibi_hub@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/jasmineanderson/chibi/chibi_hub/client
16 verbose Darwin 17.7.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v10.9.0
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 126
22 error chibi_hub@1.0.0 dev: `webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js`
22 error Exit status 126
23 error Failed at the chibi_hub@1.0.0 dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 126, true ]
```

---

I see that the issue seems to be with the webpack but I'm not sure how to fix it.
Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Did you by any chance sudo your npm install command? Looks like you have a permissions error: /Users/jasmineanderson/chibi/chibi_hub/client/node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server: Permission denied

Also, could you try deleting the node_modules folder completely and running npm install again to see if that fixes it?

Comment: Ill post is as the answer, hope you dont mind marking it as so :)

Answer (score 0):

Change/add the development server port from package.json

Answer (score 0):

The permissions error was showing that the owner was possibly not the current user. 
Deleting the folder and reinstalling without sudo was the correct answer in this case :)